# Discord.net C# Bot - A few shards connect and disconnect continuously

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I have a Discord bot using the DiscordShardedClient using the Discord.net library, I have 16 shards that serve the guilds of the bot.

For the last few weeks the bot has been extremely slow to respond. Now just shards #9 and #10 continuously disconnect with error: Server Missed Heartbeat and then reconnect.

Now I figured this was something with the servers ping. I have the bot check the ping and it is consistently ~30ms so it is not that. Additionally plenty of bandwidth.

I also have this bot on an 8 core 16 thread server with 32GB of RAM and the Database on a separate fast server as well. I don't think there is a hardware limitation.

Additionally I upped the number of shards hoping that because I receive normally on average ~2500 commands per hour that would resolve the problem.

I also have built in spam detection, to detect and then disable for users when they spam the bot. I doubt a user spamming on a guild would crash the Shard.

Also I am familiar with the heartbeat error. It usually means the bot has hung up somewhere and cannot respond back to Discord. Usually the bot does not reconnect when it is stuck on the main task. This time however it reconnects.

A few things I noticed in my testing: The bot is faster and does not crash when demand is low overnight. I debugged the code looking for long delays and found none. Database access and command execution is extremely fast. It just appears the event from DiscordShardedClient.MessageRecieved is delayed. Also the bot does seem to get somewhat slower over time after startup. I checked for memory leaks and optimized my arrays and squeezed out almost half a gig of RAM. Still did not solve my issue.

Comment: Tough one to answer, but i would look into resource consumption. Like running out of handles (object/socket handles), any kind of leaking (are counters raising over time)..